# What is the better solution for permissions of a user to a group?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, authentication

What I want to do is a permission system. there are several permissions for a group like `GetGroup`,`UpdateGroup`,`DeleteGroup` or others and no need to add or delete.
I want to :

1. easily to change the permission of each user for a group.
2. can get relations of each user by a `group_id` or `permission_id`.

So I consider the table like:

```
CREATE TABLE [Permissions] (
    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [UserId] int NOT NULL,
    [ClaimType] int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Permissions] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);
```

So I can get if a user has permission to a group:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [Permissions] AS [p]
        WHERE ([p].[UserId] = @__userId_0) AND ([p].[ClaimType] = 0)) THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END
```

But the question is there maybe 20 permission of a group(possible) and a user will have 30 groups so there will be 600 count of permissions for a user? is is too large?

So I want to change the column of `ClaimType` to `[ClaimType] varchar(1000) NOT NULL`
and I can use 1 permission to get the all claims that a user has of a group.
like :`GetGroup;UpdateGroup;DeleteGroup`.
But it may be the better solutions and I am a newbie to ask for a better table to do it.

and the relation between the users is one's permission contains another.

for example `user01` is the top user and he has all the permissions and he give some to `user02` `user03` `user005` and then `user02` give some permission to `user0201` and `user03` give some permission to `user0301` and `user0302`
then there will be :

| Id | UserId | ClaimType | ClaimId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user01 | GetGroup;UpdateGroup;DeleteGroup | group01,group02,group03,group10,group11 |
| 2 | user02 | getGroup;UpdateGroup;DeleteGroup; | group01,group02 |
| 3 | user03 | GetGroup;UpdateGroup;DeleteGroup | group03 |
| 4 | user005 | GetGroup;UpdateGroup;DeleteGroup | group10,group11 |
| 5 | user0201 | GetGroup;UpdateGroup; | group01 |
| 6 | user0301 | GetGroup; | group03 |
| 7 | user0302 | UpdateGroup;DeleteGroup; | group03 |

and the relation will be:

```
                                    user01
                     user02         user03            user005
                     user0201    user0301  user0302
user01-user02 and user03 and user005
user02-user0201
user03-user0301 and user0302
```

and I can get all the relation of the users from a claimId (groupId).

what do you suggests the table be?

Comment: Normalize your schema. For example, this can be: users table (userid, user data), groups table (groupid, group data), permissions table (permissionid, permission data), adjacency table (adjacency1id, userid, groupid), another adjacency table (adjacency2id, permissionid, adjacency1id).

Comment: Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**